# scala playframework filter by List

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have an  `Seq[INT] = [1,2]`

1,2 are IDs of an Entity.

Can I make in Scala Slick a filter on a Seq? I don't want to iterate over the Seq.

thanks.

Something like this:

```
def getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(ids: Seq[Int]) = db.run{
    //processTemplates.filter(x => x.approved === true && x.deleted === false).result

    for {
      p <- ProcessTemplatesModel
      if p.id inSetBind ids
    } yield p

  }
```

**UPDATE**

```
def getEditProcessTemplateData(processTemplateId: Int) = Action.async {
    //Get all steps of this process templates
    val stepIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplateIds(processTemplateId)

    val process = for {
      allApprovedProcessTemplates <- processTemplateDTO.getApprovedProcessTemplates //Get all approved process templates
      processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId) // Get the Process Template
      prerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      postConditions <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPostConditionsDTO.getProcessPostConditionProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      approvedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.approveprocess)
      trainedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess)
      processSteps <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId)
      // Step prerequisites
      processStepsPrerequisites <- getProcessStepsPrerequisites(stepIds)
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForStepPrerequisite(stepIds)
      // Step post conditions
      processStepsPostConditions <- getProcessStepsPostConditions(stepIds)
      processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepPostConditionProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPostConditions <- getProcessTemplateForStepPostCondition(stepIds)
      // Derived processes
      derivedProcesses <- getDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses <- getProcessStepsDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      // Process to process step
      processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates <- getProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep <- getProcessTemplateToProcessStepId(stepIds)
      responsible <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all responsibles for this process template
      accountable <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getAccountableProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all accountables for this process template
      consulted <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getConsultedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
      informed <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getInformedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
    } yield (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed)

    process.flatMap({ case (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
    processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
    processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed) =>

      Future.sequence {
        processSteps.map {
          step =>
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)
            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {

              processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates).map (pres => {
                println("test", pres) // they are printed
                step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)
              }
              )

              println("PREREQ", prereqTemplates)

//              step.stepPrerequisites = Some(prereqs)
              step
            })
        }
      }.map {
        stepTemplates =>
          Ok(Json.obj(
            "allApprovedProcessTemplates" -> allApprovedProcessTemplates,
            "processTemplate" -> processTemplate,
            "prerequisites" -> prerequisites,
            "postConditions" -> postConditions,
            "approvedProcessTemplate" -> approvedProcessTemplate,
            "trainedProcessTemplate" -> trainedProcessTemplate,
            //       Step prerequisites
            "processStepsPrerequisites" -> processStepsPrerequisites,
            "processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate" -> processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate,
            "processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites" -> processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites,
            // Step post conditions
            "processStepsPostConditions" -> processStepsPostConditions,
            "processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate" -> processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate,
            "processTemplatesForStepPostConditions" -> processTemplatesForStepPostConditions,
            // Derived processes
            "derivedProcesses" -> derivedProcesses,
            "processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses" -> processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses,
            // Process to process step
            "processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates" -> processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates,
            "processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep" -> processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep,
            "steps" -> stepTemplates,
            "responsible" -> responsible,
            "accountable" -> accountable,
            "consulted" -> consulted,
            "informed" -> informed
          ))
      }


    })
  }
```

Comment: `processTemplates.filter(x => x.id  inSet(ids)).result` could that be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
def getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(ids: Seq[Int]) = {
  val q = processTemplates.filter(_.id.inSetBind(ids))
  db.run(q.result)
}
```

Or a for comprehension:

```
def getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(ids: Seq[Int]) = {
  val q = for (p <- ProcessTemplatesModel if p.id.inSetBind(ids)) yield p
  db.run(q.result)
}
```

Comment: I got some errors: `nferred type arguments [Boolean] do not conform to method filter's type parameter bounds [T <: slick.lifted.Rep[_]]` and `found   : processTemplateDTO.this.ProcessTemplates => Boolean required: processTemplateDTO.this.ProcessTemplates => T
`

Comment: @Felix: Updated.

Comment: It compiles, but returns () ... there should be 2 items in list

Comment: but I think its empty because of asyncrounisity ... I add the whole code above

Comment: Problem is the changed values are not available in Ok()

Comment: any tips for me?

Comment: You need to chain your futures, you are not chaining the database query. Go through this blog, you will have better understanding of futures.  
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

Comment: @ChetanKumarMeena can you explain me how to chain them?

Comment: using map and flatMap operations as mentioned in the blog